# View with 2 ListViews and headers moves the other listview

Tags: android, android-listview

In my view I have 2 listviews, both have a header. When I scroll one list the other listview moves too (not a lot) but it moves enough where the header is no longer visible.

If I remove the headers this does not happen though.

in my xml I set `android:splitMotionEvents="true"` but that didn't do anything

this is how I set my header in my listviews

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle saved){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sin_preplan_layout,container,false);

    sinList = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.sin_listView);
    prePlanList = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.preplan_listView);

    sinList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    prePlanList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sin_preplan_header,(ViewGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.header_layout_root));

    prePlanList.setHeaderDividersEnabled(true);
    prePlanList.addHeaderView(v2);
    sinList.addHeaderView(v2);

    return v;
}
```

any ideas as to why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the same instance twice to different views, which is discouraged. Try this:

```
View firstHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sin_preplan_header,(ViewGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.header_layout_root));
prePlanList.addHeaderView(firstHeader);

View secondHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sin_preplan_header,(ViewGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.header_layout_root));
sinList.addHeaderView(secondHeader);
```